# Excel INDEX MATCH COUNTIF

Tags: excel

I know this is very simple, but I'm quite stuck on that. I have a very simple file with the following columns: [image]

I need to count how many people have chosen the fruit specified in column C.
I tried to do something like

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$8,MATCH("*"&$C1&"*",$A$1:$A$8,0))
```

And it correctly finds the first person corresponding to a given fruit, but how to make it count the total number of people?
I've tried using countif, but I'm missing something...

Comment: `=countif(A:A,"*"&C1&"*")` should do it?

Comment: I recognize the fruits example shown - where is the original question?:

Comment: No, I need to find the number of people corresponding to a given fruit, not to count the number of fruit occurrences!

Comment: So you deleted the original? Shame as that was a good example for others to see the use of index() with match() and wildcards...

Comment: *"No, I need to find the number of people..."*: I don't see in your example how that is different. Could you please provide an example **with** the expected output, such that it shows how those two interpretations lead to different results?

Comment: @trincot Sir, absolutely agree with you and second that, query posted and explanation provided in the solution comment of yours is quite contradictory, Thank you sir, for pointing out, !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be sure to not match a substring, like count "apple" in "pineapple", you'll have to cover several cases:

- when the word occurs at the start of the list
- when the word occurs at the end of the list
- when the list only has that word
- when the word occurs anywhere else in the list

So then the formula for cell C1 becomes:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*, "&C1&",*") +COUNTIF(A:A,C1&",*")+COUNTIF(A:A,"*, "&C1)+COUNTIF(A:A,C1)
```

This assumes the comma separated list always has exactly one space after the comma, and none before it.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to count the names associated with a given fruit, not the numer of times a fruit shows up in the column A.

Comment: Do you mean that in the names column you can have multiple names in one cell? Or that the cell can be empty? Or multiple cells with the same name? The example does not really show this. Can you update the example so it represents all possible cases? Can you also add the expected result for the example?

Answer (score -1):

[image: I hope this helps]

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A8,"*apple*")
```

and if you want to use the cell as a reference

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8,"*"&C1&"*")
```